# Assign Number to Foreach Variables

Tags: php, variables, foreach

I want to create a list of variables from a foreach loop.  I have an array like so

```
array(5) { 
    [0]=> string(105) "http://a4.mzstatic.com/us/r30/Purple5/v4/06/f2/02/06f20208-1739-4fda-c87f-171d73b912a7/screen480x480.jpeg" 
    [1]=> string(105) "http://a1.mzstatic.com/us/r30/Purple1/v4/53/89/0b/53890b90-c6a5-4db3-cfb9-d6314bf9cfd1/screen480x480.jpeg" 
    [2]=> string(105) "http://a3.mzstatic.com/us/r30/Purple1/v4/8f/31/b3/8f31b351-c9d7-e545-0ace-e09fcb390264/screen480x480.jpeg" 
    [3]=> string(105) "http://a5.mzstatic.com/us/r30/Purple3/v4/e7/5f/de/e75fde7b-dc5f-5b26-e531-abf07c409317/screen480x480.jpeg" 
    [4]=> string(105) "http://a1.mzstatic.com/us/r30/Purple3/v4/27/ce/c6/27cec64e-7e6d-7135-cc76-d0132151dadb/screen480x480.jpeg" 
}
```

and I'd like to assign each to it's own variable.  I want the final output to be something like

```
$var0 = "first array url";
$var1 = "second array url";
etc...
```

I think I want something like this but it's not quite the right syntax.

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    $var[$key] = $value;
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Why? It's far easier to work with an array than to have to keep track of how many variables you have

Comment: So you're copying the values of one array to another array?

Comment: Can I be so arrogant and go ahead and ask why you need it? It's irrational, thus it's easier to work with an array

Comment: Agree with @MarkBaker, it's much easier to use an array

Comment: Thanks JamShady, that is what I am looking for!

Comment: You're gonna regret it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach($array as $key => $value) {
    ${"var{$key}"} = $value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The function you are searching for is [extract](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php).

Just use it after your foreach loop given in your example.

```
$vars = [];
foreach ($array as $i => $value) {
    $vars['var'.$i] = $value;
}
extract($vars);
```